# Corpus of utterances and transcribed words for testing speech recognition algorithms

Tags: data-request, english

I am looking for a free English data set to use for testing different ASR API's.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few for money,  but the only one that I know of that is free is the [Buckeye Corpus](http://buckeyecorpus.osu.edu/).  About 40 hours of sound and matching transcripts. You have to register, but there is no cost for non-commercial users.

Comment: do you know which ones (that may or may not cost money) are the easiest to use? I've had success with CMU_ARCTIC and LDC93S1 (TIMIT...) but am looking for more.

Comment: I am not sure about ease of use, but the [Linguistic Data Consortium](https://www.ldc.upenn.edu/) has many data sets.  Select the button for Catalog,  then search. On the search window at lower right select "speech recognition" under recommended applications and if you want add a language restriction. You should get _many_ options.